# 3D Tiles port from Cesium to Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, cesiumjs

I'm looking at porting the 3D Tiles implementation from Cesium to Three.js.
A few questions:

Q1. Is anyone aware of an existing Three.js implementation under way?

Q2. The 3D Tiles spec is still unreleased. Are there any big changes expected in the next 3 months?

Comment: Q1.yes or jo. Q2. Yes or no. Both are very good answers.

Answer (score 1):

Q1. I am not aware of any [3D Tiles](http://cesiumjs.org/2015/08/10/introducing-3d-tiles/) port to Three.js underway.  However, 3D Tiles uses [gltf](/questions/tagged/gltf) under the hood, and there is a new glTF implementation in Three.js that may prove helpful for a port.

Q2. [Disclaimer, I work with the Cesium team, but I don't work on 3D Tiles myself, and I can't speak for the team or the spec.]  As far as I know the spec is not yet finalized, and the 3D Tiles implementation has not yet been brought into the Cesium master branch.  So if you're looking to start a port after the spec has stabilized a bit, you may want to wait at least until 3D Tiles comes into master.

Comment: I hear ya. We cant wait for final spec. We are prepared to redsctor. Thanks